# Apache proxy pass all urls and rewrite only one specific url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a website running the Ghost Blog engine in the back end. I configured the subdomain blog.domain.com to proxy to ghost engine (localhost:2368) but I need to verify that subdomain in google search console so I need the blog.domain.com/googlefile.html to return a specific string (that same string is available at domain.com/googlefile.html). How do I do that?
My virtual host config:

```
    ServerName blog.example.com
    ServerAlias *.blog.example.com

    #here is what I tried
    #RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} blog\.example\.com
    #RewriteRule googlefile.html https://example.com/googlefile.html

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:2368/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:2368/
```

Btw. all domains are https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to enable SSLProxyEngine so I can proxy https urls and also use mod_rewrite with proxy ignore url

```
    SSLProxyEngine On # enable SSLProxyEngine
    ServerName blog.example.com
    ServerAlias *.blog.example.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} blog\.example\.com
    RewriteRule googlefile.html https://example.com/googlefile.html [P]

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass googlefile.html ! # ignore the rewrited url
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:2368/ 
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:2368/
```